# LibGDX - scaling causes sprites to have a flickering line when moving

Tags: android, graphics, libgdx, game-engine

A GIF's worth a thousand words: https://i.imgur.com/tojuEMl.gifv

A still image:

[image]

That tiny gray horizontal line isn't supposed to be there. But on resolutions that aren't the same as the camera/viewport resolution, that line flickers in and out of existence when the sprite moves.

New to LibGDX so sorry if I mess up the terminology here! I'm currently running my game with a 360x640 world viewport. When I run the desktop version with that exact size, it works fine, no flickering line.

But when I change the resolution to something with *the same aspect ratio*, like 450x800, or a different aspect ratio like 480x800, the sprites start to flicker. As the sprite moves around, a horizontal line appears above the sprite. My guess is that this is because of some issue caused by the resizing making it so that the sprite isn't being drawn on an integer pixel.

My code looks something like this:

```
    float WIDTH = 360;
    float HEIGHT = 640;
    this.camera.position.set(WIDTH, HEIGHT / 2, 0);
    this.spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    this.entities.add(new PlayerCharacter(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2));
    this.viewport = new FitViewport(WIDTH, HEIGHT, this.camera);
    this.viewport.apply(true);
```

Is there a way to force the rendering to not go to decimal pixel values and always round (down)? Or another approach to get rid of the flickering when scaling to slightly different aspect ratios?

Related: I thought FitViewport is supposed to always preserve aspect ratio. It seems to be doing that - I get black bars on the side when I change to 480x800. So why is it still having the flickering problem?

Edit: Not certain, but this may only be happening on desktop builds. I built an APK and it doesn't seem to have the same problem, although I'm getting black bars on the side on a phone with the same resolution (LG G4 which is 16:9) which is also odd.

Comment: Add padding to your sprites when you pack them. It's drawing the edge of the adjacent Sprite on your atlas.

Comment: Is there any way to do that programmatically? (i.e. load the sprite and then add padding to it with libgdx). I'm using a big set of sprites intended for RPGMaker so it'd take a long time to pad them with a tool I think since I'd have to split them all first.

Comment: It would be rather convoluted. There's a free desktop app called Shoebox that can split a texture atlas into separate files. Then you could use LibGDX TexturePacker.

Comment: Okay, I will look into that. Thanks!